# How to add a value from a response to the statistics output in SoapUI?

Tags: soapui

In SoapUI you can view the statistics of a load test by click on the statistics icon.

From here, you can export the results to a file.

At present it exports the times, threads, bytes etc.

Is there any way I can append a value from the response to this file?

I want to keep the times and threads etc but I want to add a value from a XML node in the response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via a groovy script.

- Add a groovy script step into your test case in soapUI.
- Right click and select Get Data > Test Step > Response and the corresponding field, soapUI will automatically create the code for you as below  (only if you use pro version, yu can do this otherwise you need to write code by yourself)

  > ```
  > ${object1#Response#declare namespace ns2=\'http://namespace.suha.com\';
  > ```
  >
  > //ns2:namespaceResponse[1]/methodname[1]}

This code takes the corresponding field's value.

- Create a variable as below

  > def object1= context.expand( '${object1#Response#declare namespace
  >   ns2=\'http://namespace.suha.com\';
  >   //ns2:namespaceResponse[1]/methodname[1]}' )
- Up to now you’ve taken the value of the required field from the response message and created a variable with the value of the field. Now you can print the variable to the logs as below.

> ```
>    `log.info (“object1")`
> ```

- You can create a .txt file and write the variable into this file as below.

  > ```
  > today = new Date()
  > sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm")
  > todayStr = sdf.format(today)
  > new File( "D:/" + todayStr + "report.txt" ).write(object1, "UTF-8" )
  > ```